# Why this HQL is not valid?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql

The error is:
Error: org.hibernate.QueryException: can only generate ids as part of bulk insert with either sequence or post-insert style generators

HQL:

```
insert into CategoryProduct (category, product) 
select c, p from Category c, Product p 
where c.id = 252 and p.id = 554
```

The categoryProduct is a entity with embedded Id:

```
@EmbeddedId
protected CategoryProductPK categoryProductPK;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: looks like you may not have the PK column defined as auto-increment in the database.

Comment: Yes,my problem is: insert a row with embedded id. I was researching for that. Maybe HQL not supported.

Answer (score 2):

The exception seems to be thrown from [`org.hibernate.hql.ast.HqlSqlWalker`](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-core/blob/f73f158b3203516ca3ccd51180baf7f648bdf1b2/src/org/hibernate/hql/ast/HqlSqlWalker.java) at:

```
IdentifierGenerator generator = persister.getIdentifierGenerator();
if ( !supportsIdGenWithBulkInsertion( generator ) ) {
    throw new QueryException( "can only generate ids as part of bulk insert with either sequence or post-insert style generators" );
}
```

and the decision is made at

```
public static boolean supportsIdGenWithBulkInsertion(IdentifierGenerator generator) {
    return SequenceGenerator.class.isAssignableFrom( generator.getClass() )
        || PostInsertIdentifierGenerator.class.isAssignableFrom( generator.getClass() );
}
```

So it seems that Hibernate expects you to be using a generator with is a sub-type of `SequenceGenerator` or `PostInsertIdentifierGenerator`. What generator are you using?

Comment: Thanks, I know that.
CategoryProducts has a composite primary key. 2 fields (CategoryId, ProductId are primary key)